# Unable to get ToMany to work in Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm following the Tastypie docs, and have found myself utterly stuck.  I have the following:

API:

```
class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
    milestones = fields.ToManyField('ProjectTrackerServer.projects.api.MilestoneResource', 'projects', related_name='project', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Project.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'project'


class MilestoneResource(ModelResource):
    project = fields.ToOneField('ProjectTrackerServer.projects.api.ProjectResource', 'project')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Milestone.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'milestone'
```

[UPDATE:  The above API worked - based one the models below ]

Here are my models.

MODEL - Milestone:

```
from django.db import models
from ProjectTrackerServer.projects.models import Project
class Milestone(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='projects')
    name = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    due_date = models.DateField()
    completed_date = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

MODEL - Project:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Project(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     start_date = models.DateField()
     end_date = models.DateField()
     pm_id = models.IntegerField()
     status = models.IntegerField()
     slug = models.SlugField()

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if not self.slug:
             self.slug = slugify(self.name)[:50]
             return super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I still get the same error:

{"error_message": "'Project' object has no attribute 'milestones'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\resources.py\", line 192, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\resources.py\", line 406, in dispatch_detail\n    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\resources.py\", line 427, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\resources.py\", line 1058, in get_detail\n    bundle = self.full_dehydrate(bundle)\n\n  File \"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\resources.py\", line 654, in full_dehydrate\n    bundle.data[field_name] = field_object.dehydrate(bundle)\n\n  File \"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tastypie\fields.py\", line 690, in dehydrate\n    the_m2ms = getattr(bundle.obj, self.attribute)\n\nAttributeError: 'Project' object has no attribute 'milestones'\n"}

Comment: can you post your model as well? That would help

Comment: You are missing related name=milestones in the Project-Milestone relation.

Comment: I've included my models in the update.

Comment: using 'projects' and related_name='project' solved the problem! Thanks Unlimited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the posted code I figure out that your Milestone model should look like this:

```
class Milestone(models.Model):
    project = ForeignKey(Project, related_name='milestones')
```

UPDATED:

Your working resource should look like this:

```
class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
  milestones = fields.ToManyField('ProjectTrackerServer.projects.api.MilestoneResource', 'projects', full=True)
class Meta:
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'project'


class MilestoneResource(ModelResource):
    project = fields.ForeignKey(Project, 'project')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Milestone.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'milestone'
```

Comment: I tried, but same error. I've added my models, if it helps.  (p.s. I get the error '__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)' with your code, I need to add an extra arg, e.g. 'projects', in order to rid the error)

Comment: The GOOD news is that I finally receive a different error, but not sure what 'Options' object is referring to?  Does it not understand 'projects'?

Comment: {"error_message": "'Options' object has no attribute 'api_name'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", ...File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\fields.py\", line 465, in get_related_resource\n    if related_resource._meta.api_name is None:\n\nAttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'api_name'\n"}

Comment: No Options model, so I am even more confused.  Just Project and Milestone.

Comment: When I remove 'projects' and switch back to 'project' - I get old error. When I add 'projects' I get the Options error.  So, curious, why use 'projects'?  I only have multiple milestones instances in a project...not multiple projects in a milestone.

Comment: because your related name in the Milestone model with project is projects.

Comment: it should work. I will test the code and give you working version a bit later.

Comment: It worked...thanks so much, it worked...must have flushed the cache or something, but the following code worked (see updated 2)  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

::Additional resources::

[This blog has an excellent django-tastypie reverse relationship example](http://djangoandlove.blogspot.com/2012/11/tastypie-following-reverse-relationship.html)

When I had the error **AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'api_name'\n"}**

I had the example line typed out as

```
 milestones = fields.ToManyField('ProjectTrackerServer.projects.api.Milestone', 'projects', full=True)
```

Make sure you are listing the "..api.Milestone**Resource**

~Also~

If you're getting an empty list where the relationships are, make sure that the second argument you pass into the ".ToManyField" matches your related name specified in your models file.

```
milestones = fields.ToManyField('ProjectTrackerServer.projects.api.MilestoneResource', 'projects', full=True)

class Milestone(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='projects')
    ...
```