# reverse lookup by ForeignKey in Tastypie

Tags: tastypie

I have a post model and a comment model that holds the comments that were made for a particular post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    comment_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Now I want my Post resource to include URI to all the comments attached to a particular post.

I do know I can use `fields.ForeignKey` to represent which post my comments belong to, but I want the API to have the URI of all the comments that belong to the post in the post object. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PostResource(ModelResource):
     comments = fields.ToManyField(CommentResource, 'comments')
```

I had been answered similar question before. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822280/unable-to-get-tomany-to-work-in-tastypie/14830622#14830622)

Comment: Yes it works just fine. Think you :)

But I finally decided to use filtering by ID to get all the comments with a normal Foreign Key relation. That provides me Pagination too

Comment: and would you please look over [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818962/how-to-represent-unique-together-in-tastypie) for me?