# How to get tastypie to do a reverse lookup on foreign key?

Tags: django, tastypie

I have two django models: biology and occurrence.  They have a one-to-one relationship. The biology model has a foreign key to occurrence, and the tastypie biologyResource follows this relationship and displays the corresponding occurrence data correctly. I am trying to get reverse lookups to work in the API. When I try to access the occurrenceResource, I get an error

```
"error: "The model '2' has an empty attribute 'occurrence' and doesn't allow a null value.""
```

My tastypie resource classes look like this

```
class biologyResource(ModelResource):
    occurrence = fields.ToOneField("API.API_resources.occurrenceResource", "occurrence")
    class Meta:
        queryset = biology.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'biology'


class occurrenceResource(ModelResource):
    biology = fields.ToOneField("API.API_resources.biologyResource", "id", full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = occurrence.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'occurrence'
```

I have seen [some similar stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838828/reverse-lookup-by-foreignkey-in-tastypie), but they mostly deal with many-to-many relationships. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one rule very useful in such cases. Almost always the attribute of resource field is an attribute of the model field.

if your model has field:

**my_field** = model.WhateverField()

So Resource definition will have to have:

my_field = fields.WhateverField("Whatever", attribute="**my_field**")

How do you access biology through occurrence?

```
>>> biology_object.occurrence # I assume your model name is `Occurrence`
```

And other way:

```
>>> occurrence_object.biology # I assume your model name is `Biology`
```

So `occurrence` and `biology` are properties of model in other words they are attributes.

```
class biologyResource(ModelResource):
    occurrence = fields.ToOneField("API.API_resources.occurrenceResource", attribute="occurrence")
    class Meta:
        queryset = biology.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'biology'


class occurrenceResource(ModelResource):
    biology = fields.ToOneField("API.API_resources.biologyResource", attribute="biology", full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = occurrence.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'occurrence'
```

In case of trouble copy paste your models.

Comment: This was really helpful.  I am not sure I completely understand what the attribute field is, but your point about thinking about how to access biology through occurrence was the breakthrough point.  When I add attribute = 'drp_biology', then it works.  My full table name is "drp_biology"